# How to click on the element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to click on "create post" button of this element:

```
<div class="l61y9joe j8otv06s a1itoznt qwtvmjv2 kiex77na lgsfgr3h mcogi7i5 ih1xi9zn ippphs35 a53abz89" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow" id="js_2f">Create Post</div>
```

But this id (*id="js_2f"*) has a random value:

I did it this way but didn't work !

```
wait = WebDriverWait(self.browser, 20)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "//*[text()='Create Post' and contains(@id, 'js_')]"))).click()
```

How can i click on it Using Xpath method ?

Answer (score 1):

Following should help:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(text(),"Create Post")]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below xpath with `contains`

```
//div[contains(text(),'Create Post')]
```

Comment: please check again my post i did some changes, because there somethings i already did

Comment: Can you please share your url ? Also check if your element is not in the iframe. Would be great if you provide error information

Answer (score 0):

You can try to perform a click on this element using link text

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("Create Post")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text() = 'Create Post']")
```

Comment: please check again my post i did some changes, because there somthings i already did

Comment: provide the full error log, for understanding the problem

Comment: 'File "C:/Users/jhon doe/PycharmProjects/FilesLibrary/AutomateFCB_INST.py", line 29, in upload_FCB
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,  "//*[text()='Create Post' and contains(@id, 'js_')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: '

Comment: did you try the solutions which I mentioned in my answer? Please try and if the error still exists, provide this error only

Comment: I got this error for both 

`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Create Post"}
----------------------------

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[contains(text(),"Create Post")]"}`

Comment: i got this error after some changes !
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="l61y9joe j8otv06s a1itoznt qwtvmjv2 kiex77na lgsfgr3h mcogi7i5 ih1xi9zn ippphs35 a53abz89" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow">...</div> is not clickable at point (277, 296). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_3ixn"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>Create Post</kbd> button is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[data-hover='tooltip'][data-tooltip-display]"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-hover='tooltip' and text()='Create Post'][@data-tooltip-display]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: didnt work , i got this error message

`obj.upload_FCB()
  File "C:/Users/jhon doe/PycharmProjects/FilesLibrary/AutomateFCB_INST.py", line 31, in upload_FCB
    (By.XPATH, "//div[@data-hover='tooltip' and text()='Create Post'][@data-tooltip-display]"))).click()
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: i got this error after some changes
`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div class="l61y9joe j8otv06s a1itoznt qwtvmjv2 kiex77na lgsfgr3h mcogi7i5 ih1xi9zn ippphs35 a53abz89" data-hover="tooltip" data-tooltip-display="overflow">...</div> is not clickable at point (277, 296). Other element would receive the click: <div class="_3ixn"></div>`